# I need to script a function (Javascript) that takes all the string after the '/' but stops before the '?'

Tags: javascript

I'm running a workflow in Dell Boomi and the API only returns the account ID in the top level string, which looks like this -

```
api.tempo.io/core/3/user-schedule/5e5316c73011ed0c8f8b722e?from=2021-01-01&to=2021-01-31
```

I need to store - `5e5316c73011ed0c8f8b722e`.

Is there a way I can pull the string I want from that using JavaScript?

Comment: [`URL`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/URL)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
s="api.tempo.io/core/3/user-schedule/5e5316c73011ed0c8f8b722e?from=2021-01-01&to=2021-01-31"

search='schedule';
start = s.indexOf(search) + search.length + 1 ;
end = s.indexOf('?');

result = s.substring(start,end);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make it like this:

```js
    const url = 'https://api.tempo.io/core/3/user-schedule/5e5316c73011ed0c8f8b722e?from=2021-01-01&to=2021-01-31';   
    const res = new URL(url).pathname.match(/(?<=\/)[a-f0-9]+$/i)[0];
    
    console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way, creating clear function names that are potentially reusable:

```js
const getPathname = (url) => {
  return new URL(url).pathname
}

const getLastPath = (pathname) => {
  const paths = pathname.split('/')
  const [result] = paths.slice(-1)
  return result
}

const h = 'http://'

const s = 'api.tempo.io/core/3/user-schedule/5e5316c73011ed0c8f8b722e?from=2021-01-01&to=2021-01-31'

const result = getLastPath(getPathname(h+s))

console.log(result)
```